# How do I Define a Module Which Displays Some Graphics and Returns Some Data?

Tags: graphics, core-language, scoping, output

I want to bundle some actions of a task in a module to call it a few times. The task shall display some Graphics and it shall return some data (as a list).

But I can't do that (it would have been possible in Mma 4, where a Semicolon after Show did not suppress the display as in later versions, especially in the current one).

Consider

```
    Task:= 
Module[{}
      ,co=Table[{x,Cos[x]},{x,0,2*Pi,2*Pi/10}];
       si=Table[{x,Sin[x]},{x,0,2*Pi,2*Pi/10}];

       Show[{ListPlot[co,PlotStyle->Red]
            ,ListPlot[si,PlotStyle->Green]
            ,Plot[Cos[x], {x,0,2*Pi}, PlotStyle->Red]
            ,Plot[Sin[x], {x,0,2*Pi}, PlotStyle->Green]
            }
           ]    (* HERE! no Output, if there is a ; after the bracket *)
       {1,2,co}
      ];                (* Task *)
```

If I call Task, I get:

[image: strange result]

**This is a rather strange result!** Why are there multiple copies of Show's output interleaved with the list of the line below (the data, I want to return from my Task)? I just expect one image and one list?

If I add a semicolon after the cosing bracket in the line marked "HERE!", I get

[image: expected picture, but not what I am after]

which is what I expect, but not what I am after. 
I want to produce 
1st) a graphics (composed of several ones) on the screen,
2nd) a list of results computed in the module.

I know how to produce such an oputput, but to do so I would have to "unbundle" my module.

**What is the silver bullet to create both a graphics on display and a result from a Module?** (possibly one with parameters unlike my very much simpliefied example).

[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlsUg.png]

Comment: Just `Print` your plots, add a semicolon after the `Print` command, and do the other stuff

Answer (score 2):

**Why are there multiple copies of Show's output interleaved with the list of the line below (the data, I want to return from my Task)?**

You are performing list multiplication on graphics and data.  Effectively {a}*{b,c,d}.

**What is the silver bullet to create both a graphics on display and a result from a Module?**

Return a list

```
Task := Module[{}, co = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/10}];
   si = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/10}];
   {Show[{ListPlot[co, PlotStyle -> Red], 
      ListPlot[si, PlotStyle -> Green], 
      Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
      Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, 
       PlotStyle -> Green]}]    ,(*HERE! no Output,if there is a;
    after the bracket*) {1, 2, co}}];
```

Alternatively, if you have v10, us an Association

```
Task:= Module[{a = Association[]},
  a["plot"]=Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,2 Pi}];
  a["data"]={1,2,3};
  a
]
```

Now your plot can be extracted with `Task["plot"]` and your data with `Task["data"]`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I did not know about Association before. But I looked it up immediately. That one looks good to me because it is expandable to return several different categories of results such bthat one can easily extract the right one from the result without so much danger to miscount the position in the resultif it is a list as in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not very elegant but you could just have `Task` return all of the desired items and then display them outside of `Task`:

```
Task := Module[{si, co, x, g}, 
  co = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/10}]; 
  si = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/10}]; 
  g = Show[{ListPlot[co, PlotStyle -> Red], 
     ListPlot[si, PlotStyle -> Green], 
     Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Green]}];
   {g, 1, 2, co}]
results = Task;
results[[1]]
results[[{2, 3, 4}]]
```